# Check excel file is protected (with and without password)

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need to open an excel, and if it doesn't open, I need to determine if it's because of any of these cases:
-- Excel is protected
-- Excel is password protected
-- Excel is corrupt.

I have to use a completely free library for commercial purposes. So after a lot of searching, I ended up choosing NPOI.

It's strange, but I originally tried to access the isprotected property of the excel to determinate which protection it has, but for that I need to open the excel first, which will fail if it really isprotected.
I don't understand anything.

```
        using (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream))
        {
            return workbook.IsProtected;
        }
```

Now, I'm working with this idea. I try to open it, if everything goes well --> it's not protected with or without a password.

If I receive an exception, I try to open it with a random password, hoping that there will be some kind of exception that I can handle to determinate incorrect password and therefore it is using password or not password needed to determinate is protected without password...

But here I get blocked again. Can I use NPOI to open an excel with a password? Do you know of any other (commercially free) option that It can?

```
public static bool CanOpenExcel(IFormFile file)
{
    using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidFormatException ex)
        {
            return CanOpenProtectedExcel(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private static bool CanOpenProtectedExcel(Stream stream)
{
    try
        {
//Cannot use the next line. It doesnt exist this constructor with 2 arguments
            using (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream, "dummyPassword"))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It seemed like an easy thing to do at first, but, now, it's as complicated as it's getting me?

Comment: Would the following resource help:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia, and for password checking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.haspassword?view=excel-pia

Comment: @bdcoder - Thanks for your help. Not working, to get access to this property I need to open the excel first, and that will raise an exception because it has password. So, to check if it has password, I need to open it first causing an exception... no idea what is happenning here

Comment: I created two excel files - one that is password protected and then one that is not.  When I use an application to compare the two, the one that is password protected has the following text in the file: "<encryption xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/encryption" -- perhaps you could read the excel file as text and check for the string above -- which would indicate the file is password protected -- disclaimer - I have no idea about how Excel stores files that are password protected, I was only interested in seeing if a difference shows up that you could use.